# CVCalendar Blank but No Errors

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to use the CVCalendar pod and just can't get it to load anything. There are no error messages in Xcode, but i must be doing something wrong. Spent the whole day trying to figure this out.

https://github.com/Mozharovsky/CVCalendar/

1) I installed the cocoa pod thing and and imported CVCalendar

2) Right underneath the import i create 2 protocols - CVCalendarViewDelegate and CVCalendarMenuViewDelegate
(i have the feeling this might be the problem - havent worked with delegates before and im still pretty new to Xcode)

2) I create the two views and in the inspector i change the class names to CVCalendarMenuView and CVCalendarView

2) Then created outlets for them.

3) And then i added this

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    menuView.commitMenuViewUpdate()
    calendarView.commitCalendarViewUpdate()
}
```

In a test project, the whole things looks like this:

```
import UIKit
import CVCalendar

protocol CVCalendarViewDelegate{}
protocol CVCalendarMenuViewDelegate{}

class Test: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var menuView: CVCalendarMenuView!
    @IBOutlet var calendarView: CVCalendarView!

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        menuView.commitMenuViewUpdate()
        calendarView.commitCalendarViewUpdate()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

The menu view appears as a blank field. The calendar view doesn't appear at all. No dates no buttons nothing.

Comment: Did you get it working?

Answer (score 1):

First of all download full project from https://github.com/Mozharovsky/CVCalendar/ (push clone or download button). There you can find full demo of the CVCalendar  developer. You will have this:

[image]

And I fixed your code:

> ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit
import CVCalendar

class ViewController: UIViewController, CVCalendarViewDelegate, CVCalendarMenuViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet var menuView: CVCalendarMenuView!
@IBOutlet var calendarView: CVCalendarView!

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Appearance delegate [Unnecessary]
    calendarView.calendarAppearanceDelegate = self

    // Animator delegate [Unnecessary]
    calendarView.animatorDelegate = self

    // Menu delegate [Required]
    menuView.menuViewDelegate = self

    // Calendar delegate [Required]
    calendarView.calendarDelegate = self
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    menuView.commitMenuViewUpdate()
    calendarView.commitCalendarViewUpdate()
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

/// Required method to implement!
func presentationMode() -> CalendarMode {
    return .MonthView
}

/// Required method to implement!
func firstWeekday() -> Weekday {
    return .Sunday
}
}
```

> Main.storyboard

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="10117" systemVersion="15G31" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" initialViewController="BYZ-38-t0r">
<dependencies>
    <deployment identifier="iOS"/>
    <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="10085"/>
    <capability name="Constraints to layout margins" minToolsVersion="6.0"/>
</dependencies>
<scenes>
    <!--View Controller-->
    <scene sceneID="tne-QT-ifu">
        <objects>
            <viewController id="BYZ-38-t0r" customClass="ViewController" customModule="stackoverflow_39028382" customModuleProvider="target" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                <layoutGuides>
                    <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="top" id="y3c-jy-aDJ"/>
                    <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="bottom" id="wfy-db-euE"/>
                </layoutGuides>
                <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="8bC-Xf-vdC">
                    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="600" height="600"/>
                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                    <subviews>
                        <view contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="KhD-VO-LEi" customClass="CVCalendarMenuView" customModule="CVCalendar">
                            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="28" width="600" height="57"/>
                            <color key="backgroundColor" name="controlHighlightColor" catalog="System" colorSpace="catalog"/>
                            <constraints>
                                <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="57" id="d0p-pY-lAt"/>
                            </constraints>
                        </view>
                        <view contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="8CS-QV-kqC" customClass="CVCalendarView" customModule="CVCalendar">
                            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="84" width="600" height="415"/>
                            <color key="backgroundColor" white="0.66666666666666663" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                            <constraints>
                                <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="415" id="Lmo-yR-ea1"/>
                            </constraints>
                        </view>
                    </subviews>
                    <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                    <constraints>
                        <constraint firstItem="KhD-VO-LEi" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="y3c-jy-aDJ" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="8" id="7y9-B3-7Pg"/>
                        <constraint firstItem="8CS-QV-kqC" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="8bC-Xf-vdC" secondAttribute="leadingMargin" constant="-20" id="Bce-Pi-kYh"/>
                        <constraint firstItem="8CS-QV-kqC" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="y3c-jy-aDJ" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="64" id="WsH-l1-nX9"/>
                        <constraint firstItem="KhD-VO-LEi" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="8bC-Xf-vdC" secondAttribute="leadingMargin" constant="-20" id="ut9-R1-Exb"/>
                        <constraint firstAttribute="trailingMargin" secondItem="KhD-VO-LEi" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="-20" id="wAU-K8-TMN"/>
                        <constraint firstAttribute="trailingMargin" secondItem="8CS-QV-kqC" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="-20" id="wpf-0X-gor"/>
                    </constraints>
                </view>
                <connections>
                    <outlet property="calendarView" destination="8CS-QV-kqC" id="GND-0P-wUz"/>
                    <outlet property="menuView" destination="KhD-VO-LEi" id="inF-0o-ViY"/>
                </connections>
            </viewController>
            <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="dkx-z0-nzr" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
        </objects>
    </scene>
</scenes>
</document>
```

**Result of this code:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think your mistake is here:

```
protocol CVCalendarViewDelegate{}
protocol CVCalendarMenuViewDelegate{}

class Test: UIViewController {
```

The docs aren't all that clear but where it says to 'add these protocols' you need to **add them to the class** ie:

```
class Test: UIViewController,CVCalendarViewDelegate,CVCalendarMenuViewDelegate {
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer of Vasily Bodnarchuk worked great.

However, when in Landscape mode, the header in the menuView appeared twice. I solved this by placing the delegate declarations in `viewDidLoad()` instead of `viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool)`.