# Setting up CVCalendar

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm trying to implement CVCalendar with my project. I have everything in, but at the end it asks for me to connect outlets. Here is an image of the instructions:

[Click here for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnXxF.png)

I have no idea what to do as I am new to swift and xcode development. Here is the link to the github page: https://github.com/CVCalendar/CVCalendar

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: The following post has answered my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39028382/cvcalendar-blank-but-no-errors?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

I assume you've extended `CVCalendarMenuViewDelegate` and `CVCalendarViewDelegate` on your `ViewController` and implemented the delegate methods required for CVCalendar such as `presentationMode` and `firstWeekday`.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    ...
}

extension ViewController: CVCalendarMenuViewDelegate {
    ...
}

extension ViewController: CVCalendarViewDelegate {
    func presentationMode() -> CalendarMode {
        return CalendarMode.monthView
    }

    func firstWeekday() -> Weekday {
        return Weekday.monday
    }
}
```

The last thing to do is to connect CVCalendar's `menuView` and `calendarView` objects to this class. This means that whenever an action occurs with a `calendarView` or `menuView` object the action knows to be routed to the delegate methods of your `ViewController` because you've attached it as an outlet.

This can be done in InterfaceBuilder by holding the control key and dragging from the menuView and calendarView to the top of the scene and then choosing the delegate to connect to, as shown in this image.

[Connecting an outlet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGtjJ.png)

This can also be done programmatically in your `ViewController's` `viewDidLoad` method.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    calendarView.delegate = self
    menuView.delegate = self
}
```